# HTTP connect with Transparent proxy

Tags: http, proxy, connect, digest-authentication

I am trying to write (and understand) a transparent proxy.

My setup would look like this

Client Browser ---> TProxy ----> Upstream Proxy ------> cloud

When the client browser makes a GET request, the idea is TProxy would then CONNECT to the Upstream proxy. The upstream proxy requires digest authentication. So, essentially the flow would look like

```
Client Browser ---> TProxy --------> Upstream Proxy ---------------> cloud 
GET BBC.co.uk
                    CONNECT 
                                       407 PROXY AUTH REQUIRED
                    CONNECT
               (with proxy-authorization)

                                       200 OK
                    GET BBC.co.uk
```

I am confused what happens once CONNECT with authorization succeeds.
Am I suppose to modify the original GET request now to include a 
Proxy-Authorization header?

or would the original GET request be then tunnelled in another http header something like

```
HTTP Header
 Proxy Authorization
  HTTP Header (GET BBC.CO.UK)
  Data
```

or I can just pass the original GET request as is?

I am just starting with http and would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you authenticate upstream from your transparent proxy, the `Proxy-Authorization` header applies only to the CONNECT.
The GET requests happen within the tunnel, so the upstream explicit proxy is not supposed to see them, and for sure does not expect any proxy authentication headers on them.

In short, you do not need to worry about the GET, but not because of the answer given above, but because there is a tunnel between the transparent proxy and the site, and the explicit proxy only sees and authenticates the CONNECT.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This seems logical to me. However, I am not able to see this explicitly mentioned in the RFC. Can you point me to a reference in the spec

Comment: I can't find it in the RFC either, but nevertheless, this is how clients behave. Note that GET requests within CONNECT tunnels are considered un-proxied (i.e. because they are tunneled), so any proxy authentication does not apply to them by definition.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as nested headers in HTTP.

A proxy - whether transparent or not - always terminates the HTTP connection from the client, and initiates a new one to the server.

That means that the HTTP GET from the client goes to your TProxy. TProxy creates a new GET request to Upstream Proxy. Ideally, TProxy will simply pass on all the headers. That would make it (nearly) undetectable.

The same goes in reverse for the response headers.

In reality, proxy servers will, and in many cases have to, manipulate some headers. They will often add their own header (for instance, to alert the communication partners to the presence of a proxy), and they can also manipulate existing headers.

So, the short answer to your question: whatever header field your TProxy receives, pass it on unchanged unless you fully understand the implications.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. My doubt is do I add the Proxy-Authorization header to the original GET request and if I don't would the upstream proxy reject the GET request. I set up squid on my laptop with digest authentication enabled and saw that once the authentication completes, the browser is sending Proxy Authorization in every further GET request.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How would you add a header to the **original** GET request, which has already been sent (and received its reply) by the time you know the digest? In subsequent GET requests, the browser would add the headers for you; you would not need to do anything but pass them on.

Comment: Hi Kevin, sorry maybe I am not being clear. When the GET request(bbc.co.uk) reaches the TProxy, TProxy buffers the GET request. TProxy then sends a CONNECT to the upstream proxy. The upstream proxy responds with authentication required. TProxy then re-tries with authorization header and then receives 200 OK for connect. All this time, the original GET request from the client browser has NOT been send. Once the CONNECT succeeds, TProxy will then send the GET request. Do I now modify the GET request to include the authorization header?

Comment: I get it. I would argue that the browser should be sending the CONNECT, and your TProxy should simply pass it through. Otherwise, it's not transparent. That said, yes, in your scenario you would add the header to the GET, but you'll probably run into more issues because even on subsequent GETs, the browser wouldn't add the header (because it never knew about the CONNECT). You'll need to implement some form of session tracking to keep track of which GETs do or don't get an authorization header.

Comment: @KevinKeane - OP is converting raw SSL handshake in a transparent proxy to explicit CONNECT. There is no CONNECT sent from the proxy, and passing through is not the right solution.